# push is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function, push

I am new in JavaScript. I wrote function to save data to local storage, but every time I try to save a data,it doesnt work and it always get this error: push is not a function.and this error just appears a second in console.log and dissappear by itself. apart from this my problem is it doesn't save the data to the local storage How can I fix this? (the function,not working  is "addTodoToStorage"

```
const form =document.querySelector("#todo-form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");
const todolist= document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCardBody= document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCardBody= document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("clear-todos");

eventListeners();
function eventListeners() {
    form.addEventListener("submit",addTodo); 
  
}
function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodo = todoInput.value.trim();
if (newTodo === ""){
    showAlert("danger","please type something");
}
else{

addTodoToUI(newTodo);
addTodoToStorage(newTodo);
showAlert("success","successfully added");
}
    e.preventDefault();
}
function getTodosFromStorage() { 
    let todos;
 
    if(localStorage.getItem("todos") === null){
        todos = [];
    }
    else{
        todos= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    }
    return todos;
   }
 function addTodoToStorage(newTodo) {
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
     todos.push(newTodo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos));
    
}
function showAlert(type,message) {
    const alert = document.createElement("div");
    alert.className= `alert alert-${type}`;
    alert.textContent= message;
    firstCardBody.appendChild(alert);
    //set time out
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert.remove();
    },2000);
    
}
function addTodoToUI(newTodo) {

    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href="#";
    link.className="delete-item";
    link.innerHTML='<i class = "fa fa-remove"></i>';
listItem.className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";

listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodo));
listItem.appendChild(link);

todolist.appendChild(listItem);

todoInput.value = "";

}
```

Comment: Log the value of `todos`. It probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: If the console log 'disappears', it's perhaps because your page is being refreshed. Most browser devtools allow you to preserve logs across page transitions.

Answer (score 0):

As for the error msg disappearing after a while, it's because you haven't prevented the default behavior of the form. Or rather, you have prevented it at the bottom, which is fine if you want the form to prevent GET-ing(its default *method*) to the URL(in *action* attribute).

But if an error occurs inside the submit handler (in your case, it probably does), the JavaScript stops the execution, and the form continues its default behavior, because there's is nothing to tell it that it can't do that. It can, so it will. HTML forms be ratchet like that. Due to which the page reloads.

For the part why there's an error, I couldn't find any errors here. If this is the same code you're using, there shouldn't be a problem.

**EDIT**
I tried to reproduce your example as follows and it works. It adds items to my localStorage successfully.

```
<form id="todo-form">
    <input id="todo" type="text" />
</form>

<script>
    const form =document.querySelector("#todo-form");
    const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");

    eventListeners();
    function eventListeners() {
        form.addEventListener("submit",addTodo); 
      
    }
    function addTodo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newTodo = todoInput.value.trim();
    if (newTodo === ""){
        showAlert("danger","please type something");
    }
    else{
    addTodoToStorage(newTodo);
    showAlert("success","successfully added");
    }
    }
    function getTodosFromStorage() { 
        let todos;
     
        if(localStorage.getItem("todos") === null){
            todos = [];
        }
        else{
            todos= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
        }
        return todos;
       }
       
     function addTodoToStorage(newTodo) {
        let todos = getTodosFromStorage();
        todos.push(newTodo);
        localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos));
    }
    
    function showAlert(type,message) {
        const alert = document.createElement("div");
        alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;
        alert.textContent = message;
        document.body.appendChild(alert);
        //set time out
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert.remove();
        }, 2000);     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.I got your point. ın my case i use exact code what i wrote here, it doesn't save to local storage.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example(see the edit) and it works. It adds items to my localStorage successfully.

Comment: I tried your code. I appreciate it but it didn't work. what could it be else?

Comment: it worked for me though. It still does. That's bizarre.